# Restricting the Length of a String using XML Schema

Tags: xml, xsd

I have a XSD file where i should restrict the element in xml to have limited number of characters

```
<ClientCode>CDX</ClientCode>
    <!-- Client ID defined / Type: String [4..15 chars] / Obligatory -->
```

How can i limit the characters ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<xs:element name="ClientCode" type="string4-15"/>

<xs:simpleType name="string4-15">
   <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
      <xs:minLength value="4"/>
      <xs:maxLength value="15"/>
   </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```